# Sign Out google play game services in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

How to sign out gpg in unity ? and change button text to sign in ?

i tried in this but nothing :

```
Social.localUser.Authenticate(success => 
{
    LoadData();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To sign the user out, use the `PlayGamesPlatform.SignOut` method.

```
using GooglePlayGames;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

// sign out
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SignOut();
```

After signing out, no further API calls can be made until the user authenticates again.

See this [GitHub post](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) for more information and also this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow) for more details on the sign-in flow.

Comment: Update: From version 0.11.1, Google has removed the SignOut method https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/UPGRADING.txt